# Understanding Haskell's Bool Deriving an Ord

Tags: haskell, boolean

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types) presents the `Bool` type:

`data Bool = False | True deriving (Ord)`

I don't understand the reason for comparing `Bool`'s.

```
> False `compare` True
LT
> True `compare` False
GT
```

What would be lost if `Bool` did not derive from `Ord`?

Comment: Well, you couldn't have a `Map` of bools.  What is there to gain by not having an `Ord` instance?  Also, notice you couldn't trivially derive `Ord` for ANY type that includes `Bool` without a pre-existing `instance Ord Bool`.

Comment: How about indicator functions e.g. fromEnum . (`elem` [1,2,3]) which is 1 if applied to an element of the set and 0 otherwise?

Comment: I think it should be called "deriving an `Ord` instance" instead of "deriving from `Ord`".

Comment: thanks @chaosmasttter. I just updated with your correction.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Bool` forms a [bounded lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29#Bounded_lattice)* where `False` is *bottom* and `True` is *top*. This bounded lattice defines a (total) ordering where `False` really is strictly less than `True`. (They are also the only elements of this lattice.)

The boolean operations `and` and `or` can also be looked at as *meet* and *join*, respectively, in this lattice. Meet finds the greatest lower bound and join finds the least upper bound. This means that `a && False = False` is the same thing as saying that the lower bound of bottom and anything else is bottom, and `a || True = True` is the same thing as saying that the upper bound of top and anything is top. So meet and join, which use the ordering property of the booleans, are equivalent to the boolean operations you are familiar with.

You can use `min` and `max` to show this in Haskell:

```
False `min` True = False -- this is the greatest lower bound
False  &&   True = False -- so is this

False `max` True = True  -- this is the least upper bound
False  ||   True = True  -- so is this
```

This shows that you can define `&&` and `||` *just* from the derived `Ord` instance:

```
(&&) = min
(||) = max
```

Note that these definitions are not equivalent in the presence of [a different kind of bottom](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) because `(&&)` and `(||)` are short-circuiting (non-strict in the second argument when the first is `False` or `True`, respectively) while `min` and `max` are not.

Also, a small correction: The `deriving` clause does not say that`Bool` "derives from" `Ord`. It instructs GHC to derive an instance of the typeclass `Ord` *for* the type `Bool`.

* More specifically, a *complemented distributive lattice*. More specifically still, a [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29).

Comment: There is a difference between `(&&) = min; (||) = max` and the typical definition: They have different strictness properties so, for example, they behave differently wrt to bottoms ("bottom" in the sense of `undefined` etc). `(&&)` and `(||)` are short circuiting.

Comment: Good point. I can add the usual "up to bottoms" caveat if you think it would help.

Comment: Could you please tell me the significance of `meet` and `join`? I read your paragraph on them twice, but I'm not understanding. Specifically, what is the meaning of the `least upper bound` & `greatest lower bound` of a Bool?

Comment: @DavidYoung: Why should they be any different? `min` and `max` are defined in terms of `compare` or the comparison operators, and there is no reason why the strictness of those has to be different than for `(&&)` and `(||)`

Comment: @newacct `(&&)` and `(||)` are defined in terms of a short circuiting pattern match. For `compare` to give a result (on `Bool` at least) it must evaluate both arguments since there is a possibility that they are equal. Consider the difference between `True || undefined` and `True \`max\` undefined`

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Sounds like a good idea to me. Although, it might be good to differentiate it from the "bottom" in the `Bool` bounded lattice.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Actually, `max` and `min` are defined in terms of comparison operators, not `compare`

Comment: @newacct The comparison operators themselves might be defined in terms of `compare` depending on how the deriving instance mechanism works in this case. Either way, it really doesn't matter. There is a difference between things like `True || undefined` and `True \`max\` undefined` and that's my point.

Comment: @DavidYoung: "There is a difference between things like True || undefined and True `max` undefined and that's my point." But *what* makes them different? They're both just functions; unless something is different about their declarations, there is no reason why they must behave differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54672/discussion-between-david-young-and-newacct).

Comment: @Rein - thank you! I think I just met you at LambdaJam - thanks again for your teaching of Applicatives to me in the hotel.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yep! You're welcome! Pleasure to meet you too.

Answer (score 18):

The `Ord` instance for `Bool` becomes much more important when you need to compare values that contain `Bool` somewhere inside. For example, without it we wouldn't be able to write expressions like:

```
[False,True] `compare` [False,True,False]

(3, False) < (3, True)

data Person = Person { name :: String, member :: Bool } deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

etc.

Answer (score -2):

It is because Haskell designers made a mistake! I never saw a mathematics textbook that mentioned ordering of booleans. Just beacuse they can be it does not mean with should. Some of us use Haskell exactly because it disallows/protects us from confusing/nonsensical things in many cases but not this one.

`instance Ord Bool` causes `a => b` to mean what you expect `a <= b` to mean!

Earlier arguments in favour of `instance Ord Bool` where that you can make more types comparable implicitly. Continuing that line of argument some might want to make every type comparable impicitly and even have weak dynamic typing and omit type classes altogether. But we want strong typing exactly to disallow what is not obviously correct, and `instance Ord Bool` defeats that purpose.

As for the argument that Bool is a bounded lattice. Unlike boolean:={True,False}, what we have in Haskell is Bool:={True,False,bottom} is no longer a bounded lattice since neither True nor False are identity elements in the presense of bottom. That is related to those comments discussing && vs min etc.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. Many monad instances are incorrect in the presence of bottom as well, and yet we still use them.

Comment: It is quite common in Haskell to reason about things "up to bottoms", and I have included a caveat to this effect. We can do this because it is "morally correct" in the sense explored in [Fast and Loose Reasoning is Morally Correct](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html) (PDF): if two terms have equivalent semantics in a total language then they have *related* semantics in a partial language, and so we can still reason effectively about semantics in Haskell despite its partiality.